# Visa Refusal. 179(b) of the IRPR - What to include?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, international-travel

What can I include so that the visa officer doesn't think I would like to stay back in Canada?

> • I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your
>   stay as a temporary resident, as stipulated in paragraph 179(b) of the
>   IRPR, based on the purpose of your visit.
>
> • I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your
>   stay as a temporary resident, as stipulated in paragraph 179(b) of the
>   IRPR, based on your family ties in Canada and in your country of
>   residence.

I am attending a cousin's wedding in Canada. I intended to stay with her for 2 weeks.

I included the invitation letter from her with details about her wedding and that I will be staying with her, her passport along with her husband's passport, and the wedding invitation.

I included details about my family back in my home country and that they were not accompanying me.

Some additional information:

- I am from India.
- My flight tickets in and out of Canada were booked and provided.
- I am self employed and provided my business registration in India and my company registration in the UK along with business bank documents and sufficient funds.
- I provided travel history with 4 UK visas, Schengen Visa, UAE visa.
- I provided sufficient personal funds to show I have no reason to stay in Canada.
- I included a picture of us together.

There are Regulated Canadian Immigration Consultants (RCICs) which I can hire but that cost is too high.

Any advice?

Comment: What family do you have in India?

Comment: Parents & Siblings.

Comment: Could the picture of you with your cousin have gone against you? Showing a closer tie than you intended? It says "family ties in Canada."

Comment: The picture was at my wedding so I didnt think it would be a reason for refusal.

One of the points in the application needed Relationship Proof, I dont know how to prove cousin and it was not part of the Drop Down List.

The list had 
Brother
Sister
Uncle
Aunt
Other - I chose this.

But I am sure a country such as Canada would understand having cousins in another country.

Comment: You’re not likely to receive any answer that will be earth shattering. From what you have provided and assuming it’s accurate plus having 4 UK and Schengen visas, you fit the profile of a genuine visitor. Some of the refusals are just nonsensical and based on broad stereotypes particularly for applicants from developing nations.

Comment: I know, I was just looking out for anyone who might have been through a similar path and could share some advice. I would like to try again and I don't know what additional information to include that I didn't include the first time. This is my first visa refusal.

Comment: In addition, I have shown investments well over CAD $150,000. How could the visa offer think someone would leave that kind of investment and 'run away' in Canada.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that you would lose the value of those investments if you were living illegally in Canada?  You would still legally own the stocks, real estate, or whatever.

Comment: @Warren Do you Have property? What type of business - does it require your physical presence in India?

Comment: Parents and siblings are not usually considered strong family ties for visa purposes, unless there are special circumstances such as a parent being physically dependent on you. A spouse and children are what they are usually looking for here.

Comment: @phoog No, there won't be any reason to think I would lose the investments. I am not sure how that could put my application in a negative view.

Comment: @Traveller. I do not have any property on my name. I have a software development business. I have a lot of clients and that requires physical presence.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I am married and my wife was to be travelling with me. Her visa was refused with the exact same reason.

Comment: @Warren You have a good travel history but maybe, in the eyes of an Immigration official, questionable ties to home. A software development business might be viewed as being able to be run from anywhere (you mention “business registration in India, and company registration in the UK”,for example). Your investments might be seen as being liquid and able to be accessed from or transferred to Canada. You have family in Canada and your wife was going to travel with you.

Comment: @Traveller Yes I agree. The investments are liquid and can be transferred out. However investing in real estate is not an option for me at this time. I guess I have to re-work the application to show that I need to leave Canada for my own benefit.